# Google Cloud Scheduler: Why cloud function runs successfully but logger still shows error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I set up a google cloud scheduler job that triggers a cloud function through HTTP. I can be sure that the cloud function is triggered and runs successfully - it has produced the expected outcome.
However, the scheduler job still shows "failed" and the logger is like:

```
{
  "insertId": "8ca551232347v49",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "jobName": "projects/john/locations/asia-southeast2/jobs/Get_food",
    "status": "UNKNOWN",
    "url": "https://asia-southeast2-john.cloudfunctions.net/Get_food",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
    "targetType": "HTTP"
  },
  "httpRequest": {},
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
    "labels": {
      "job_id": "Get_food",
      "location": "asia-southeast2",
      "project_id": "john"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-10-22T04:08:24.521610728Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/john/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-10-22T04:08:24.521610728Z"
}
```

I have pasted the cloud function code below with edits necessary to remove sensitive information:

```
import requests
import pymysql 
from pymysql.constants import CLIENT
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import time 
from DingBot import DING_BOT 
from decouple import config
import datetime 

BUCKET_NAME = 'john-test-dataset'
FOLDER_IN_BUCKET = 'compressed_data'
LOCAL_PATH = '/tmp/'



TIMEOUT_TIME = 500


def run(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
        
    while True:
        # some code that will be break the loop in about 200 seconds

    DING_BOT.send_text(msg)
    return 'ok'
```

what I can be sure of is that the line right before the end of the fucntion, `DING_BOT.send_text(msg)` executed successfully. I have received the text message.

What cloud be wrong here?

Comment: Would you like to edit the question to share the code of the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can copy and use to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: How long take your fonction to be executed? Did you try to set the return code at the end of your function `return 'OK', 200`?

Comment: Could you please take a look at your [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/products/operations) and get further logs? It's needed for information to better understand your case, as without using Cloud Scheduler, your Cloud Function is working per your say.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I tried it but it did not have any effect. The cloud function runs successfully, but the cloud scheduler shows "failed" nonetheless.

Comment: @gso_gabriel I have looked into stackdriver... the above pasted error message is the only thing I could get.  The logs for cloud function shows that all has run successfully. The cloud scheduler shows "failed" nonetheless, and when I dig into its detailed logs in stackdriver, the error message is the only thing I could get.

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C, you didn't answer the first part of my question: How many seconds take your function?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  There is a while loop in the code which does some query search on DB and It takes about 200 seconds to finish; I have already set the function timeout to the max (540 sec) and I still got the issue described as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common problem because of partial UI of Google Cloud Console. So, I took the hypothesis that you set up your scheduler only with the console.

So, you need to create, or to update it with [command line (GCLOUD)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http) or [API](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest) (but GCLOUD is easier), to add the ["attempt-deadline" parameter.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http#--attempt-deadline)

In fact Cloud Scheduler also have a timeout (60s by default)and if the URL don't answer in this timeframe, the call is considered as fail

Increase this param to 250s, and it should be OK.

*Note: you can also set retry policies with the CLI, it could be interesting if you need it!*

Comment: You are right, I did set up scheduler only with the console.